# Introducing differential privacy in two different ways

Tags: differential-privacy, gaussian-noise

I would like to investigate if it is possible to introduce Differential Privacy (DP) to a model via both adding Laplacian noise to the training data and then training with DP-SGD updates. Is it a valid way to introduce DP ?

In other words, if we separately applied Laplacian noise to the data the system would be assigned with (ε1,0)-DP per epoch and if we trained with DP-SGD it would be assigned with (ε2,δ2)-DP per epoch. What would be the (ε,δ) values if we applied both ? Is this an application of the composition theorem ?